# Notification Email Entry Won't Work For Date Box Value

Tags: google-app-maker

So I am using the following in the onValueEdit field of an entry form

```
var widgets = widget.root.descendants;
var to = 'xxxx@yyy.com';
var subject = 'Delivery Date Change For: ' + widgets.ProjectName.value;
var msg = "The Delivery Date for [ " + widgets.UsersPosition.value + " ] on [ " + widgets.ProjectName.value + " ] has been changed;
sendMessage(to, subject, msg);
```

So when a user changes a Delivery Date (by adjusting a Date Box) a notification email is sent out. I would like to add the actual in the Date Box but when I add **" + widgets.DeliveryDate.value + "** it says it is unrecognized.

Since the DeliveryDate is a Date Box, do I need something different? **widgets.DeliveryDate.???**

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"value" property is the one you need. Please note that it's JavaScript Date object so in some cases you need to convert it. But code you provided looks good to me.

What do you mean by "unrecognized"? Could you provide error details?

BTW: it's better to use Server Script to generate email message.

Comment: So if I have var msg = "The Delivery Date for [ " + widgets.UsersPosition.value + " ] on [ " + widgets.ProjectName.value + " ] has been changed to [ " + widgets.DeliveryDate.value + " ] I get the following error: "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
at Projects_Edit.Panel16.DeliveryDateBox.onValueEdit:4:162"

Comment: For using a Server Script, should I just used that same code and on the onValueEdit have the function name? Also is there a better way to do the emails? It would be great to actually be able to do some kind of rich text/html like formatting (bold, logos, spaces, hyperlinks, etc)

Comment: It seems that there is no widget named "DeliveryDate" (or it's not under "widget.root"). Please use code completion to check available widgets. Please check what widget is mentioned in onValueEdit line 4 symbol 162.

Comment: As about Server Scripts: you probably save new delivery date to a record. In this case please use Model's onSave event to send email (https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/events).